Fix the differing color of two mosaiced band images of Landsat in ArcGIS
I am trying to apply Mosaic to new raster tool in two band 1 images, But after doing so, the final raster is being generated with a different color from the previous rasters and with an overlap too. How do I achieve a perfect mosaiced raster images for any band images of Landsat 7 & 8?


"Perfect mosaiced raster images" seems an impossible goal. More information on the statistics of the bands and the steps you have taken to feather them together would help.

Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap, and which version?
